# Insert popify for radiobuttons options

Tags: r, shiny

I did a popify for my radiobutton. However I would like to separate the popify in my radiobuttom options. For example, for "filter1", I would like to insert a popify for the "All properties" and other popify for "exclude properties" options. Is this possible ?? The executable code is below.

```
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(


  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(


      popify(  
        radioButtons("filter1", h3("Select properties"),
                     choices = list("All properties" = 1, 
                                    "Exclude properties" = 2),
                     selected = 1),
        title= "Select Proprierties",
        content = paste0("Filter 1 refers to.....")),

        radioButtons("filter2", h3("Select farms"),
                     choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                    "Exclude farms" = 2),
                     selected = 1),
       sliderInput("bins",
                    "Number of bins:",
                    min = 1,
                    max = 20,
                    value = 30)
           ),

    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
    x    <- faithful[, 2]
    bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

    # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
    hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at `popify` we see that it works only on full `shiny` elements,  but you want to add it not to the whole element but a child HTML element of it.

`addPopover` seems thus to be the better option. However, we see that the function adds the popover on an HTML element given by an `id`. Problem is that the row where you want to have the popover does not have an `id` and the `addPopover` function does not allow for specifying the element by other means than the `id`.

Thus, we have to work around:

1. Use JS to add an `id` to the radio button rows (I use `shinyjs` for that).
2. Use this created `id` in `addPopover`

*Note*. In order to make `addPopover`  run you need to include at least one `shinyBS` component. From the help file:

> There must be at least one ‘shinyBS’ component in the UI of your
>        app in order for the necessary dependencies to be loaded. Because
>        of this, ‘addTooltip’ and ‘addPopover’ will not work if they are
>        the only shinyBS components in your app.

```r
library(shinyBS)
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs) ## needed to tamper with the HTML

ui <- fluidPage(
   useShinyjs(),

   titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel( 
         radioButtons("filter1", h3("Select properties"),
                      choices = list("All properties" = 1, 
                                     "Exclude properties" = 2),
                      selected = 1),
         title= "Select Proprierties",
         radioButtons("filter2", h3("Select farms"),
                      choices = list("All farms" = 1, 
                                     "Exclude farms" = 2),
                      selected = 1),
         sliderInput("bins",
                     "Number of bins:",
                     min = 1,
                     max = 20,
                     value = 30),
         ## need to include at least one bs element, adapt
         bsTooltip("bins", "The wait times will be broken into this many equally spaced bins",
                   "right", options = list(container = "body")) 

      ),

      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)

## use JS to add an id attribute to the elements where you want to add the popover
add_id_js <- paste0(
   "$('#filter1').find('.radio > label').attr('id', function(i) {",
   "return 'filter1_row_' + i})")

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ## once the UI is loaded, call JS function and attach popover to it
   session$onFlushed(function() {
      runjs(add_id_js)
      addPopover(session, "filter1_row_0", "My Popover", "Content")

   })


   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      # generate bins based on input$bins from ui.R
      x    <- faithful[, 2]
      bins <- seq(min(x), max(x), length.out = input$bins + 1)

      # draw the histogram with the specified number of bins
      hist(x, breaks = bins, col = 'darkgray', border = 'white')
   })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Popover]

Comment: Hello thothal, any idea for this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63092033/issue-involving-map-generation-in-shiny